# Column 'Hits' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql

i got a sql code that can not work:

```
INSERT INTO t_ruleid(logdate,month,hour,ruleid,Hits,Host,cdn_id) select b.logdate,b.month,b.hour,b.ruleid,b.Hits,b.Host,b.cdn_id from t_ruleid_back as b ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Hits=Hits+b.Hits;
```

it got error Column 'Hits' in field list is ambiguous

How can i make it work?

thanks!

Comment: Remove the ambiguity, so `Hits=t_ruleid.Hits+b.Hits`

Comment: Thanks!      It work!

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would use `values()` to get the value of what is passed in:

```
insert into t_ruleid(logdate, month, hour, ruleid, Hits, Host, cdn_id)
    select b.logdate, b.month, b.hour, b.ruleid, b.Hits, b.Host, b.cdn_id
    from t_ruleid_back as b
    on duplicate key update Hits = Hits + values(Hits);
```

I'm not sure by `b.Hits` would generate that specific error though.

Comment: it still got the same error, Column 'Hits' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: It's not b.hits. It's the missing *t_ruleid*.hits!